# Magento rest api getting error Request does not match any route

Tags: magento2, rest-api

How can i create the base url for magento.

I have this error when i hit the url to get the order can some help me to find out the solution. I am using `oauth authentication`

```
{
  "message": "Request does not match any route.",
  "trace": null
}
```

url : http://sca.followthetiger.com/api/rest/order
and pass the consumer key and all in header.

Comment: You can create Rest API module by following this tutorial.
[inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/api-magento/magento-2-custom-api/) Also, apply this command after creating the module: php bin/magento setup:upgrade Hope this help.

Comment: This doesnt answer the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

Using my localhost site url with https:// instead of http:// did the magic for me:

So: https://magento2.local/rest/V1/integration/customer/token/
Passing as body :

{"username":"user@email.com", "password":"customerpassword"}

Comment: My api key : https://snipboard.io/oN3HiP.jpg postman : https://snipboard.io/ncOurb.jpg getting error, any help thanks

Comment: Similar was the case with me. Thanks man

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong URL.  Instead of

`http://sca.followthetiger.com/api/rest/order`

you should use

`http://sca.followthetiger.com/api/rest/V1/orders/:order_id`

Answer (score 1):

This issue appeared when I tried to automatically apply a coupon code at checkout with a button click. I have created a mixin from the `Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount` JS file, and simply targeted the coupon field and entered the code via jQuery. After executing `this.apply()`, the error appeared.

What I didn't realise was that the code was also handled by Knockout, and so the field had to be updated via `this.couponCode("theCode")`, then it would work.

So to answer your question, please ensure that the URL fully matches what the API expects, which includes any parameters within the URL itself. For coupon codes, the URL template is `/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/coupons/:couponCode`, but as the browser was sending "V1/guest-carts/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456/coupons/" (notice the missing coupon code at the end of the URL), it deemed it an invalid route.

You can view all the available API routes via all of the webapi.xml files. For retrieving an order via an ID, use `/V1/orders/:id`, which is specified in vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/webapi.xml.